# Find index of cells containing my string

Tags: string, matlab, search, cells, strcmp

I have a cellarray C which contain numbers and string like that.

```
1 0 'C:\user' 41.57
2 0 'C:\user' 46.25
3 0 'C:\user' 48 
4 0 'C:\user' 48.33
```

I want to get the index of the cell which is equal to a specified name enter.

I have tried to do something like that but it didn't work

```
idx=find(strcmp([C{:,:}],'C:\User\..')
```

I need help please

Comment: Add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

To use `strcmp`, you have to use `num2str` at first to convert the double to string. Use `UniformOutput` as false since your `C` has both numbers and strings.

```
idx = find(strcmp(cellfun(@num2str, C, 'un', 0), 'C:\user'));
[row, col] = ind2sub(size(C), idx);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i have used what you told me but i get error Undefined function 'abs' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in num2str (line 65)
        xmax = double(max(abs(widthCopy(:)))); what should i do ? :/

Comment: pls edit your question by adding the code that you launched in Matlab, since i have used your input example of C and got no error ...

Comment: hi i have used this code <pre> indice = (find(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,'C:\user'),C))-330)<code> and it work for me. the only issue that i need to substract from the result 330 (which i don't konw why: maybe because i have two colonne before the colonne which contain the path) Can any one help me to find a solution instead of substracting 330 . thanks in advance